# Lifetime of Future returned by async function

Tags: rust, rust-futures

Trying to write recursive Stream, where each stream takes poll from his parent and when Poll is ready with value it makes own asynchronous fetcher to process a parent response, but I have no idea how to store the current future given by fetcher, compiler complains on lifetime until I trying to use a free async function (that not bound to struct). There incomplete example, but it illustrates the compiler error (two lines are commented in Stream implementation):

```
struct AsyncFetcher {}

impl AsyncFetcher {
    async fn fetch(&self, request: String) -> String {
        format!("Response({request})")
    }
}

enum State {
    PendingParent,
    ToProcess(Option<String>),
    Processing(Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = String>>>)
}

struct RecStream {
    parent: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>>,
    state: State,
    fetcher: AsyncFetcher,
}

impl RecStream {
    fn new(parent: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>, fetcher: AsyncFetcher) -> Self {
        Self {
            parent: Some(parent),
            state: State::PendingParent,
            fetcher: fetcher,
        }
    }

    fn with_result(result: String, fetcher: AsyncFetcher) -> Self {
        Self {
            parent: None,
            state: State::ToProcess(Some(result)),
            fetcher: fetcher,
        }
    }
}

impl Stream for RecStream {
    type Item = String;

    fn poll_next(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let ref_mut = self.get_mut();
        let future = ref_mut.fetcher.fetch("Some str".to_string()).boxed();
        
        // let future = free_fut().boxed(); // - THIS WORKS
        ref_mut.state = State::Processing(future); // Getting error 'lifetime may not live long enough'
        
        return Poll::Pending;
    }
}

async fn free_fut() -> String {
    "Free string".to_string()
}
```

Comment: Does `fetch()` need to use `self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
impl AsyncFetcher {
    async fn fetch(&self, request: String) -> String {
        format!("Response({request})")
    }
}
```

In this function, Rust is inferring that the returned future captures the lifetime of `&self` even though you never actually use it.  This makes the future non-`'static` but you are attempting to cast it to `dyn Future` which is implicitly `'static` (in the absence of an explicit lifetime annotation).

You can work around this by changing the function from `async fn` to `fn` and returning `impl Future` instead, returning an `async move` block.  Since the block won't capture `self`, the returned future will be `'static`:

```
impl AsyncFetcher {
    fn fetch(&self, request: String) -> impl Future<Output = String> {
        async move { format!("Response({request})") }
    }
}
```

You could also just drop the `&self` parameter entirely.

Note that if you do intend to use `self` in the future, the problem will resurface.  In that case you would need your `AsyncFetcher` owned by something else, or having shared ownership (`Arc<AsyncFetcher>`) and the future can own its own `Arc`.  Otherwise you are effectively trying to store a reference to a value in the same struct that owns it, which [isn't something you can (easily) do in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/501250).